# How the get the index of the duplicate pair in the scala list

Tags: scala

I have a scala list like this below:

```
slist = List("a","b","c","a","d","c","a")
```

I want to get the index of the same element pair in this list.
For example,the result of this slist is

```
(0,3),(0,6),(3,6),(2,5)
```

which (0,3) means the `slist(0)==slist(3)`
(0,6) means the `slist(0)==slist(6)`
and so on.

So is there any method to do this in scala?
Thanks very much

Comment: how is this related to `spark` ?

Comment: I've deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

There's simpler approaches but starting with `zipWithIndex` leads down this path. `zipWithIndex` returns a `Tuple2` with the index and one of the letters. From there we `groupBy` the letter to get a map of the letter to it's indices and filter the ones with more than one value. Lastly, we have this `MapLike.DefaultValuesIterable(List((a,0), (a,3), (a,6)), List((c,2), (c,5)))`
 which we take the indices from and make `combinations`.

```
scala> slist.zipWithIndex.groupBy(zipped => zipped._1).filter(t => t._2.size > 1).values.flatMap(xs => xs.map(t => t._2).combinations(2))
res40: Iterable[List[Int]] = List(List(0, 3), List(0, 6), List(3, 6), List(2, 5))
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution here. It is very gentle. And one more question, I finally find it may be a highly time-cost to calculate all pairs of this. However,what I really need to consider is to get the pair below:(0,3)
 (3,6) （2,5). which means I don't need to get the index pair (0,6) because the order in the slist. Any suggestions to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Indexing a `List` is rather inefficient so I recommend a transition to `Vector` and then back again (if needed).

```
val svec = slist.toVector
svec.indices
    .map(x => (x,svec.indexOf(svec(x),x+1)))
    .filter(_._2 > 0)
    .toList
//res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((0,3), (2,5), (3,6))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 val v = slist.toVector; val s = v.size
 for(i<-0 to s-1;j<-0 to s-1;if(i<j && v(i)==v(j))) yield (i,j)
```

**In Scala REPL:**

```
scala> for(i<-0 to s-1;j<-0 to s-1;if(i<j && v(i)==v(j))) yield (i,j)
res34: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Int)] = Vector((0,3), (0,6), (2,5), (3,6))
```